# Google Sign-In SDK 2.0.1 (GIDGoogleUser Class)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to implement the `new` signin sdk for google plus login, and trying to get this information like from the

> Previous SDK

```
NSLog(@"Email     = %@", [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail);
NSLog(@"GoogleID  = %@", person.identifier);
NSLog(@"User      = %@ %@", person.name.givenName, person.name.familyName);
NSLog(@"Gender    = %@", person.gender);
NSLog(@"User image= %@", person.image.url);
```

I did get this information:

> New SDK

```
NSLog(@"GoogleID :%@", user.userID);
NSLog(@"Email %@", user.profile.email);
NSLog(@"User :%@", user.profile.name);
NSLog(@"Image URL :%@", [user.profile imageURLWithDimension:1]);
//Gender ?
```

from this [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_profile_data)

But the problem is getting the `Gender`, i have no idea how to get it now..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find both using person.gender, person.image only.
Here person.gender is string you can use directly and person.image is NSDictionary so you can get image using key name.

Edited Answer:
Please try this for Image URL:

```
NSURL *imageURL =
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.profile imageURLWithDimension:dimension];
```

Comment: GIDProfileData don't have those two.. from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_profile_data) and it's `person.image.url` for the image (previous SDK) but the problem is for the NEW SDK,

Comment: Please try this for image : NSURL *imageURL =
        [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.profile imageURLWithDimension:dimension];

Comment: I've already added that to my edited question(32 mins. ago).. and the only problem now is the gender, do you have any idea how to get it?